# How to render a form component inside iframe in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to render my form component inside the iframe but its only rendering iframe
How to render a form component inside

```
import './App.css';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client"
import Form from './components/Form';

function App() {
  return(
    <iframe><Form /></iframe>
    
    
      
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Form Component

```
export default function Form(){
    return(
        <>
        <form target="iframe">
            <input type="text" />
        </form></>
        
    )
}
```

How to render my from inside iframe

Answer (score 0):

An iframe is primarily meant to render an external resources from another website.

It would look something like this:

```html
<iframe src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html"></iframe>
```

It appears that you are trying to render a React component in an iFrame. Unfortunately, this is not something you can do. You can render raw html if you use the srcdoc attribute like so:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uXWycyeTeCs" srcDoc='<p>Hello from Iframe</p>' ></iframe>
```

But this won't work for a react component.

If your goal is to render something outside of the React Hierarchy Tree, then you can use React Portal which would look something like this:

```js
ReactDOM.createPortal(child, container)
```

For more information, you can read this:
https://blog.logrocket.com/best-practices-react-iframes/